# How to dump a large database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I try to take a backup of a huge MySQL database via `mysqldump`. The database has millions of rows with a total size of 1.3TB.

```
CREATE TABLE PageContents
(
ID int(11) unsigned,
Added date,
Text MEDIUMTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES AllPages(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1;
```

but I receive an error after 8 hours of dumping:

```
mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table `PageContents` at row: 20946782
```

I had increased `max_allowed_packet` in `mysql.cnf`

```
max_allowed_packet  = 16G
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) claims that max value for `max_allowed_packet` is 1 Gb... you may try to use structure dump + CSV data backup. Structure backup must be divided by 2 parts. While restore, you restore structures with indices only, then load data, then restore FKs and triggers.

Comment: Have you considered LVM snapshots or a replication solution? Also, have you looked at Percona's XtraBackup instead of mysqldump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have set `max_allowed_packet` in the appropriate section `[mysqldump]` of the config file `my.cnf` and that it does not exceed the [maximal value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) of **1G**:

```
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

Or you can also specify it at runtime (without having to change my.cnf):

```
mysqldump --max-allowed-packet=1G ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `max_allowed_packet=512M` to your `mysqldump` command.

Or add `max_allowed_packet=512M` to `[mysqldump]` section of your `my.cnf`

Note: It will not work if it is not under the `[mysqldump]` section